# Find all solutions in $\mathbb C$ for $z^4 = 1$

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

To start, I write the equation in polar form:
$$|z|^4(cos^4\theta + isin^4\theta) = 1(1 + 0i)$$

Next, I want to solve for $\theta$:
$$cos4\theta = 1 \textrm{ and } sin4\theta = 0$$

$$4\theta = cos^{-1}(1) = 0$$
$$4\theta = sin^{-1}(0) = 0$$

Here is where I get stuck. 
I think that when solving for $\theta$, the $0$ also means $2\pi$ as well so I can get $4\theta = 2\pi + n2\pi$. This will turn into $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{n\pi}{2}$

My textbook says the values of $n$ yields values $\theta$ where $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$ and it seems I feel like I am almost done with the problem, but I don't know how to deal with $n$ in the above equation.

There should $n$ solutions in $z^n$, so 4 solutions. I am not entirely sure why $n$ is added into the equation. I suspect it is link to the $i$ in the polar form. Am I missing a step between where I am with the $\theta$ value and the 4 solutions for $z^4$?

Comment: You may be confused with two different $n$s:  you used $n$ as the number of solutions $(4)$, and the other $n$ comes in because you can add any multiple of $2\pi$ (i.e., $2n\pi, n \in \mathbb N$) to the arguments of cos and sin without changing their values

Comment: ah, that makes sense. But I don't think adding a multiple of $2\pi$ would help me find any solutions between $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$

Comment: Yes it will!  It is *ESSENTIAL* to you finding solutions  Your solutions are $\theta = \frac \gamma 4$ where $\sin \gamma 0$ and $\cos \gamma = 1$. $\gamma = 0$ so $\theta = \frac 04 = 0$. And $1^4 = 1$.  Fine but that's only *one*.  $\gamma = 2\pi$ is another so you have $\theta = \frac \pi 2$.  And $\gamma = 4\pi$ is another so you have $\theta = \pi$.  And $\gamma = 6\pi$ is another so you have $\theta = \frac {3\pi}2$.  And $\theta = 8\pi$ so you have $\theta = 2\pi$ and .... well, now you have gone out of range.

Comment: Thing is.  You are adding $2\pi$ to $4\theta$ not to $\theta$.  ANd this in turn results in add $\frac \pi 2$ to $\theta$.  And that *will* help you find solutions between $0$ and $2\pi$.   $4\theta = 0$ is one solution.  $4\theta = 2\pi$ is another.  $4\theta = 6\pi$ is a third and so on.  If $0 \le \theta < 2\pi$ then $0 \le 4\theta < 8\pi$ and you need to consider $4\theta = 0, 2\pi, 4\pi, 6\pi$ in order to find *all* the $0 \le \theta < 2\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure why n is added into the equation.

===

Ah!

Important.

The thing is that $\theta \equiv \theta + 2n\pi$ for any integer value of $n$ in that $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta) = \cos(\theta + 2n\pi) + i\sin(\theta + 2n\pi) = e^{i\theta}$.

So if you have $c = r*e^{i\gamma}$ and you want

$z^k = c=r*e^{i\gamma}$ so you want to find the $k$th roots of $c$.  (Note: the root $k$ that you want to find has nothing to do with the $n$ in the expression $\theta + 2n\pi$)

you want to figure $z = \sqrt[k]{r} e^{i\frac \gamma k}$.

But we have an issue.  That isn't the only root.

$c = re^{i\gamma}= re^{i(\gamma + 2\pi)}$ as well.

So $\sqrt[k]{r}e^{i(\frac \gamma k + \frac {2\pi}k)}$ will also be a root.

So will $c = re^{i\gamma}= re^{i(\gamma + 2\pi)}=re^{i(\gamma + 4\pi)}$ and $\sqrt[k]{r}e^{i(\frac \gamma k + \frac {4\pi}k)}$ will *also* be a root.

In fact we are going to have $k$ roots of $\sqrt[k]{r} e^{i\frac \gamma k}, \sqrt[k]{r}e^{i(\frac \gamma k + \frac {2\pi}k)}, \sqrt[k]{r}e^{i(\frac \gamma k + \frac {4\pi}k)}, .... \sqrt[k]{r}e^{i(\frac \gamma k + \frac {2(k-1)\pi}k)}$.

We write this as the $k$ roots $\sqrt[k]{r} e^{i(\frac \gamma k) + \frac {2n\pi}k}$ for all the $n$ where $n = 0,....., k-1$.

...

So in your case you have $4\theta = 0, 2\pi, 4\pi, 6\pi$ or $2n \pi$ for $n\in \mathbb Z$ and you what

$\theta = \frac {2n\pi}4$ for $n\in \mathbb Z$.  If we assume $0 \le \frac {2n\pi}4 < 2\pi$, we have $n = 0, 1,2,3$ and $\theta = 0, \frac \pi 2, \pi, \frac {3\pi} 2$.

===== old answer====

$\theta = \frac \pi 2 + \frac {n\pi}2$ for $n\in \mathbb Z$ so $n = ...... ,-4, -3, -2, -1, 0 , 1 ,2, 3, 4,....$

So $\theta =....., \frac \pi 2 - \frac {4\pi}2, \frac \pi 2 - \frac {3\pi}2, \frac \pi 2 - \frac {2\pi}2, \frac \pi 2 - \frac {1\pi}2, \frac \pi 2 - \frac {0\pi}2, \frac \pi 2 + \frac {1\pi}2, \frac \pi 2 + \frac {2\pi}2, \frac \pi 2 + \frac {3\pi}2, \frac \pi 2 + \frac {4\pi}2,....$

So $\theta = ...... -\frac {3\pi}2, -\pi, -\frac \pi 2, 0, \frac \pi 2, \pi, \frac {3pi}2,2\pi, \frac {5\pi}2,....$

but if we  only consider the values of $\theta$ that are unique up to equivalent values between $0$ and up to $2\pi$ we have

$\theta = 0, \frac \pi 2, \pi, \frac {3\pi}2$ and so

The roots are $e^0 = 1; e^{i\frac \pi 2} = i; e^{i\pi} =-1; e^{i\frac {3\pi}2}=-i$

.... which hopefully were the four roots you were expecting.

Geting a value of $\frac {n\pi}2$ or whatever just means to go through the possible integer values of $n$ that give values within the range $[0,2\pi)$.  That's all.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, thank you. So then $n$ does not mean that there will only be $n$ number of solutions (in this case 4 number of solutions)? Is my observation incorrect such that whatever power $z^n$ is, there will be $n$ solutions?

Comment: Right $z^n = 1$ will have $n$ solutions.  The solutions will occurat $n\theta = 0, 2\pi, 4\pi, 6\pi, 8\pi......$ or in other words when $n*\theta = 2k\pi$ for some integer $k$ or when $\theta = \frac {2k\pi}n$ where $k$ is some integer and $0 \le \theta = \frac {2k\pi}n, 2\pi$.  This will occur when $k =0,1,2,3,...., n-1$.  And those are then $n$ roots.

Comment: Hey, SO $cos(\theta) = cos(\theta + 2\pi)$ is basically telling us that for every $n$ multiple of $2\pi$, it will be a solution BECAUSE on a unit circle, $cos(\theta)$ + 360 degrees will land in the same spot, hence $0 = 2\pi = 4\pi, \dots$ basic trig that I had long since forgotten about until now haha

Comment: Well, $0$ and $2\pi$ and $4\pi$ aren't *equal* but they are *equivalent* in that they have the same trig values for any trig function.  ANd since we nearly always are only concerned with the unit circle $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ (otherwise we'd go nuts with the infinitude of things that are exactly the same) we restrict values to being between $0$ and $2\pi$.  But when we have $\sin 4\theta=\frac 12$, for example, and figure therefore $4\theta$ is either $\frac \pi 6$ or $\frac{5\pi}6$ which is true if we restrict $0\le 4\theta<2\pi$..... but.... tbc...

Comment: ... continued... So we figure if $4\theta = \{\frac \pi 6,\frac{5\pi}6\}$ then we figure $\theta= \{\frac\pi{24}, \frac{5\pi}{24}\}$. BUT we if we resricted $0 \le 4\theta < 2\pi$ the we are restricting $\theta$ to $0 \le \theta < \frac \pi 2$ and that's way too restrictive.  We are omitting for example $\theta=\frac {2\pi} 3$ gives us $\sin 4\theta=\sin\frac{8\pi}3=\sin(2\pi + \frac \pi 6)=\sin\frac \pi 6 = \frac 12$ so that is *also* a valid answer.  If we restrict $0\le \theta<2\pi$ then we are restricting $0\le4\theta<8\pi$ and $\sin 4\theta$ isn't just $\frac\pi6$ or$\frac{5\pi}6$

Answer (score 3):

The polar form $re^{i\theta}$ of complex numbers $z = x +iy$ is a wonderful thing, as are de Moivre's theorem

$(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)^n = \cos (n\theta) + i\sin (n\theta), \tag 1$

and Euler's formula

$e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta; \tag 2$

but sometimes it is just easier to avoid all the hoopla with multiple values of $\theta$ separated by $2\pi$ and stick with plain old algebra, ***viz.***

$z^4 - 1 = (z^2 - 1)(z^2 + 1); \tag 3$

$z^2 - 1 = (z - 1)(z + 1); \tag 4$

$z^2 + 1 = (z + i)(z - i); \tag 5$

each of the formulas $(3)$-$(5)$ is in fact a special case of the everyday polynomial identity

$a^2 - b^2 = (a + b)(a - b). \tag 6$

If we combine $(3)$-$(5)$ we obtain

$(z - 1)(z + 1)(z + i)(z - i) = (z^2 - 1)(z^2 + 1) = z^4 - 1; \tag 7$

since each of the distinct factors on the left is a monic polynomial we see we have completely factored $z^4 - 1$ and thus

$z = \pm 1, \; \pm i \tag 8$

are the roots of

$z^4 - 1 = 0. \tag 9$

Comment: Thank you for pointing out De Moivres formula and linking the relationship to Eulers formula and reminding me about the polynomial identity axiom. if $z = \pm 1, \pm i$, then how do you relate these roots into trignometric form? Will the solutions in trig form be $cos(1), cos(-1), sin(-1), sin(1)?$

Comment: @EvanKim:  you can convert the roots $z = \pm 1$, $ \pm i$ to polar form by observing that each is of unit modulus and so may be represented as $\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$, and equating $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ to the real and imaginary parts of $z$ (which of course will work for *any* $z$ with $\vert z \vert = 1$); thus if $z = 1$ we find $\cos \theta = 1$, $\sin \theta = 0$, whence $\theta = 0$ (the unique solution neglecting those pesky multiples of $2\pi$); with $z = 1$ we obtain $\cos \theta = 0$ and $\sin \theta = 1$, so $\theta = \pi /2$ etc.